# Localhost refused to connect in jboss(Eclipse Juno)

Tags: eclipse, jboss, localhost

I am trying to run an application like http://localhost:8080/FWar/Login.jsp and getting error that localhost refused to connect.I am using Jboss 7.1 server in Eclipse Juno.

Comment: Is there anything else running on port 8080? What is the output of the JBoss console logs?

Comment: no nothing is running...don't understand what is the problem.